# Use HashSet as Dictionary Key - Compare all elements

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashset, edges

I am checking if a total group of edges already contains the connection between 2 points.

I want to use `HashSet`'s that will contain 2 vectors as `Dictionary` keys. Then I want to be able to call a performant `Dictionary.ContainsKey(hashSet)`. I want the contains/equality check to be dependent on the Vectors in the Set.

Fex. If I add `HashSet [V000 V001]` to the Dict. I want to get `Dictionary.ContainsKey(HashSet [V001 V000])` return true. (HashSet, so the order can vary, just the same Elements)

The Problem seems to be, that the `Dictionary.ContainsKey()` method does see separately created `HashSets` as different objects, even though, they contain the same elements.

```
Dictionary<HashSet<Vector3>, Vector3> d = new Dictionary<HashSet<Vector3>, Vector3>();

HashSet<Vector3> s = new HashSet<Vector3>();
s.Add(Vector3.one);
s.Add(Vector3.zero);

d.Add(s);

HashSet<Vector3> s2 = new HashSet<Vector3>();
s2.Add(Vector3.zero);
s2.Add(Vector3.one);

bool doesContain = d.ContainsKey(s2); // should be true
```

You also may suggest a better way of doing this 'Contains()' check efficiently.

Comment: You need a new type to use as the Dictionary key. The new type will have a Hashset property and overload `.Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` (and therefore may as well implement `IEquatable`) to do the comparison you want. The `HashSet` type doesn't provide the equality comparison you want out of the box. It only does reference equality.

Comment: Don't downvote my question, just because I am new here ... very unpolite. @JoelCoehoorn This seems a very good approach, but I dont fully understand where I need to override those things. Could you give a small code example?

Comment: Dictionary<K,V> has a constructor that accepts a custom IEqualityComparer<K>: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer__0__

Comment: @Mechandrius The question was downvoted because you didn't show any effort, or research, on your part to solve this problem. If you're new here I really recommend reading through all of the help sections, and also read Jon Skeet's [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Ensuring your question is as good as it can possibly be will help you get more favourable results.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Ooh, I hadn't noticed that one before. That can be useful.

Comment: @John I have overworked the question and improved several unclear details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HashSet` type doesn't do the equality comparison you want out of the box. It only has reference equality.

To get what you want, you'll need a new type to use as the Dictionary key. The new type will have a HashSet property, and overload `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`, and may as well implement `IEquatable` at this point as well.

I'll get you started:

```
public class HashKey<T> : IEquatable<HashKey<T>>
{
    private HashSet<T> _items;
    public HashSet<T> Items
    {
        get {return _items;}
        private set {_items = value;}
    }

    public HashKey()
    {
        _items = new HashSet<T>();
    }
    public HashKey(HashSet<T> initialSet)
    {
        _items = initialSet ?? new HashSet();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // I'm leaving this for you to do
    }

    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (! (obj is HashKey)) return false;
        return this.GetHashCode().Equals(obj.GetHashCode());
    }

    public bool Equals(HashSet<T> obj)
    {
        if (obj is null) return false;
        return this.GetHashCode().Equals(obj.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I would point out is that generally speaking it is not a good idea to use `GetHashCode` as a an equality comparison (although I am also very guilty of falling into using it) as it is true, equal objects __must__ return an equal hash code, it does not follow that objects having equal hash codes are equal.  Eric Lippert has a [good article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/) dealing with `GetHashCode` and makes a passing mention to this fact (pigeon hole principle).

Comment: @pstrjds Agreed generally.. but in this case, it's literally the only reason for this type to exist. Of course, there's always scope/feature creep later.

Comment: I can see that and agree with it :)  Just that as OP is a student I wanted to be sure it was mentioned that in general this is not "best practice".

Comment: This looks like the answer. But .. It feels a bit hacky, even though, I dont understand the problem deeply. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a hashset as key.

So the keys are references where one key is one hashset reference.

The ContainsKey compare references.

For what you want to do, you can create a class that implements IEqualityComparer to pass it to the dictionary constructor.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1

If you want a full management, you should create a new class embedding the dictionary and implement your own public operations wrapping that of the dictionary : ContainsKey and all others methods you need.

```
public class MyDictionary : IEnumerable<>
{

  private Dictionary<HashSet<Vector3>, Vector3> d 
    = new Dictionary<HashSet<Vector3>, Vector3>();

  public int Count { get; }

  public this...

  public ContainsKey()
  {
    // implements your own comparison algorithm
  }

  public Add();

  public Remove();

  ...

}
```

So you will have a strongly typed dictionary for your intended usage.

Comment: Both solutions are good. But using a wrapped comparable HashSet key looks very simple and fitting. Rewriting the entire Dictionary could be useful when more special properties are desired.